# Use apturl instead of Software Center for apt: links

Tags: chromium, apturl

I've changed from Friefox to Chromium. Everything works fine except one thing:
When I hit an apt: link, it opens the Ubuntu Software Center instead of starting the installation via apturl. (Yes, it is installed)
How can I change the default handler for apt: to apturl?

(Raring x64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: Just executed `xdg-mime default apturl.desktop x-scheme-handler/apt` and the problem was solved.

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted to remove this question from the **Unanswered** section. Thank you! :)

Comment: I have to wait 2 days to do this...

Comment: You can read up about accepting your own answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).